# How to distinguish between recorded and a live vocal signals?

Tags: matlab, signal-analysis, voice

Is it possible to detect if a sample of human voice by smartphone/computer(`44Khz`) is sourced from another electrical device or originated  from a human being

I want to build a model in matlab such that, samples a vocal signal and decides whether it is a real human being talks a live or recorded, is it even possible?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Voice-activated door lock or something?  If a person is talking "live" through Skype, should that be disqualified?  What you're really testing is whether a person is actually talking in front of the mic or if their voice is being played through a speaker?

Comment: @endolith Yes I try to test whether a person is actually talking in front of the mic or if their voice is being played through a speaker.

Comment: I would focus on the properties of the speaker, then, not the microphone.  Portable/phone speakers are generally limited in bandwidth and all speakers have at least a little distortion.  Maybe you could detect intermodulation distortion of the voice or something?

Answer (score 1):

On a smartphone, flat out no. The microphones are so poor that you're lucky to get any approximation of the actual audio.

On high-quality hardware, perhaps. Barely. If you're lucky. Check for MP3 compression artifacts. If the source is not compressed with a lossy codec, you're out of luck.

Comment: I can assume the recorded is compressed, you suggest trying to detect some artifacts?

Comment: Stationary background noises will continue to be present, by definition, but speech will mask them. Perceptual compression algorithms like MP3 will discard those frequency components. So if you suddenly see the background noise disappear, you can suspect compression and thus a recording.

Comment: I disagree with the statement about smart phone microphone quality. These days most better phones use PCB mounted MEMS microphones from companies like Knowles, ST, Analog Devices, etc. which are really quite good if properly mounted. It perfectly is possible to do decent recordings with these mics, if proper software is used.

Comment: @Hilmar: What do you think their frequency response is above 5 kHz, for instance?

Comment: A good MEMS is flat to about 10kHz (within one dB or so) and then rises because of the mechanical resonance. The rise is very consistent so it can easily be EQ'd out, if that's a problem.

Comment: @Hilmar: That's true of the microphone itself, but its environment influences the real-world performance. And smartphones just aren't that ideal. As for EQ'ing out the non-flat response, that requires that you know the response curve.

Comment: @MSalters: The maker of the phone knows the response curve and how to EQ it out, no?

Comment: @endolith: You'd hope they did. But at the speed that phones are introduced and withdrawn from the market, it seems this is just one of the steps they skip.